# Completely reflashing galaxy tab 3?

Tags: operating-systems, android

How to completely erase (no more partitions) and reinstall android on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3? The digitizer went out about a month after I changed. I unplugged the new digitizer and plugged it back in and it works for about 5 seconds, then goes out, and was wondering if I could erase it completely and reinstall I'm sure that would fix the problem (assuming it's a software problem).  I've tried Odin but not sure what will completely erase the tablet I would like to use my tablet again please help! PS (Is there anything that could fix the problem via usb because I can't use the digitizer)

Comment: well, it is not possible to completely wipe the system outside the factory, or the system will be bricked. You will not get much deeper access to the system than Odin can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into recovery (turn off tablet, power+volume down, release power at the galaxy tab screen, release down button when you see recovery) and use volume buttons to highlight factory reset, power button to select. Then you could install via Odin.